# Back slash ("\n") is output literally on iOS

Tags: android, ios, node.js, mongodb, express

I am a Nodejs backend developer working with iOS developers.

We are using mongodb and have a string containing back slash ("\n") in the content field. And we find query this in db and respond to client with express response json.

The data we give in response is structured as

```
{
  content: “content is \n content"
}
```

but when the client outputs the field, “\n” is not newline, and there is a problem that is output literally.

I am not a client developer and I don't know the detailed reason.

That's why I am checking if there is a problem, and when I changed the response I gave through postman to json, I could confirm that “\n” is shown as “\n”.

However, this alone does not solve the question that the content field outputs “\n” literally on the client.

Has anyone had this experience?

I would really appreciate it if you share your experiences.

Comment: In your data, there is "/n", that should be "\n".

Comment: @sagar chauhan Ah! I made a mistake by writing on mobile. My data is back slash (\n). I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried entering \n instead of /n? alternately you can try with \n\r

Comment: I have exactly "\n" as the field value. And when I output the string in the mongo gui tool, the newline appears normally. However, after passing the object containing the string to the client as json, "content is \n content" is output literally on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Because the string iOS is getting is literally a \n as 2 characters, not as a newline.  Use an actual newline in your data if you want to send a newline.  \n is only special in code, not in string data.  If you have a situation where you need to do interpolation in code, you'll need to write a function that replaces all instances of \ with \, then all instances of \n with a real newline.

Comment: Even if the server gives the response as a json, how would it be a double back slash if the data received from iOS will be converted to an object through "JSONSerialization.jsonObject"? And if it's a double backslash issue, shouldn't the actual iOS field output as "content is \\n content"? On iOS, a single backslash is output literally.